# How to hide the Streetview street name labels on the street floor

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I need to get the street names (shortDescription) on street floor removed from streetview panorama:
[Label I want removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5O05I.jpg)

I know this is possible as seen on 
https://geoguessr.com/world/play

They seem to use the same kind of json syntax as for customizing a google maps layout
f=[{featureType:"poi",elementType:"labels",stylers:[{visibility:"off"}]}],
l={disableDefaultUI:!0,disableDoubleClickZoom:!0,clickToGo:!0,linksControl:!0,styles:f}
But I'm not even sure these labels are actualy part of the POI ...

I really need some help
Thanks !

Answer (score 8):

Try to use the showRoadLabels option on StreetViewPanoramaOptions. Works fine for me.

```
  var panorama = map.getStreetView();
  panorama.setOptions({
     showRoadLabels: false
  });
```

Docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#StreetViewPanoramaOptions

Answer (score 2):

I just had this same problem, and I figured out the problem was the *version* of the Google Maps API. Geoguessr uses an older version of the streetview panorama API. Notice the difference:

Version 3.24 (no street names): https://jsfiddle.net/922urh2j/

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.24&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initialize"></script>
```

Latest version (includes street names): https://jsfiddle.net/922urh2j/1/

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initialize"></script>
```

So far as I can tell, there's no option to disable street names if you're using the latest version of the API.

Comment: Yes thanks for your reply I also finally found out about this.