# Hide street names in Google Street View

Tags: javascript, canvas, google-street-view

Is there an easy way to hide the street names on the floor in Google Street View? I suppose that they are drawn with JavaScript onto the canvas element used to display the street panorama.
Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide the Streetview street name labels on the street floor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39271165/how-to-hide-the-streetview-street-name-labels-on-the-street-floor)

Comment: In Photoshop you can use Content-Aware fill: http://www.photoshop-bootcamp.com/how-to-remove-a-person-from-a-photograph-using-content-aware-fill-in-photoshop/

Comment: @enxaneta OP is asking about Google Street View, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/street-view#StreetViewPanorama

you must use this:
showRoadLabels: false

Comment: Please quote the relevant part here making it easy for everyone to understand it.